# NoRouteToHostException with DatagramChannel bound to wildcard address

Tags: java, networking, udp, nio, datagram

I am having trouble with this combination: I would like to bind both my sending and receiving datagram channels to system-picked port and IP (*not* loopback and *not* localhost). In the following example, this works all fine when I use "old I/O" aka `DatagramSocket` (case 1), but it fails with `NoRouteToHostException` using NIO aka `DatagramChannel` (case 3).

My API is all based around `InterruptibleChannel` and the socket created via `new DatagramSocket` doesn't have a channel associated, so I need to get this working with `DatagramChannel.open()`. A stupid workaround is case 2, where I temporarily "connect" the channel. So this might help answer why case 3 fails...

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.nio.*;
import java.nio.channels.*;

public class Test {
   public static void main( String[] args ) {
      try { test(); } catch( Exception e ) { e.printStackTrace(); }
   }    
   public static void test() throws IOException {   
      DatagramChannel tgt = DatagramChannel.open();
      tgt.socket().bind( new InetSocketAddress( 0 ));
      SocketAddress tgtAddr = tgt.socket().getLocalSocketAddress();          
      byte[] data = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };

      System.out.println( "Sending 1..." ); // ok!
      DatagramSocket src1 = new DatagramSocket( new InetSocketAddress( 0 ));
      src1.send( new DatagramPacket( data, data.length, tgtAddr ));

      System.out.println( "Sending 2..." ); // ok!
      DatagramChannel src2 = DatagramChannel.open();
      src2.socket().bind( new InetSocketAddress( 0 ));
      src2.connect( tgtAddr );
      ByteBuffer b = ByteBuffer.wrap( data );
      src2.write( b );
      src2.disconnect();

      System.out.println( "Sending 3..." ); // fails!
      DatagramChannel src3 = DatagramChannel.open();
      src3.socket().bind( new InetSocketAddress( 0 ));
      src3.socket().send( new DatagramPacket( data, data.length, tgtAddr ));
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to *send* to the address that 'tgt' is bound to, which is the wildcard address. I'm surprised that it works at all. You have to supply a proper target IP address, not 0.0.0.0.

Comment: You can use the wildcard for receiving datagrams from any network adapter. I am using this, because several users had issues with using `InetAddress.getLocalHost`. I am creating a bidirectional client, that is, I want to use the same datagram channel for sending and receiving, while maintaining the wildcard property (that receiving works from all network adapters). Also some had issues with `InetAddress.getLocalHost` not working properly (I think on Windows), and using `0.0.0.0` proved to be a viable workaround.

Comment: @Sciss I suggest you read my answer again. You are *sending* to 0.0.0.0, which doesn't make sense.